# Installing app on 2014 model / app doesn't appear

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I'm using SDK 5.1 and have tested a javascript app on the emulator. Now I'm struggling to install the app on my 2014 model.

I followed the samsung guide for 2014 models (http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00121/index.html).

I've logged in with the "develop" account, typed in the ip and clicked "start user app sync". Then I get a popup "User Apps sync requested - OK"
My problem is, that (even after several minutes) the app doesn't appear in the app-section of my tv.

I've checked my access.log of the apache and have found code 200 for the widgetlist.xml and the zip-file:

- GET /widgetlist.xml?timestamp=1420139182690 HTTP/1.1' 200 307
- GET /Widget/MyApp_0.100_Europe_20150101.zip HTTP/1.1' 200 460823

So, the tv should have received the files, but doesn't install the app.

Here is my widgetlist.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<rsp stat='ok'>
<list>
<widget id='MyApp'>
<title>Test</title>
<compression size='460823' type='zip'/>
<description>Test</description>
<download>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Widget/MyApp_0.100_Europe_20150101.zip</download>
</widget>
</list> 
</rsp>
```

Here my widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget>
<ThumbIcon>icon/ThumbIcon.png</ThumbIcon>
<BigThumbIcon>icon/BigThumbIcon.png</BigThumbIcon>
<ListIcon>icon/ListIcon.png</ListIcon>
<BigListIcon>icon/BigListIcon.png</BigListIcon>
<category>Information</category>
<autoUpdate>n</autoUpdate>
<cpname></cpname>
<cpauthjs></cpauthjs>
<login>y</login>
<ver>0.100</ver>
<mgrver>1.000</mgrver>
<fullwidget>y</fullwidget>
<srcctl>y</srcctl>
<ticker>n</ticker>
<childlock>n</childlock>
<audiomute>n</audiomute>
<videomute>n</videomute>
<dcont>y</dcont>
<network>y</network>
<widgetname>MyApp</widgetname>
<description></description>
<width>960</width>
<height>540</height>
<author>
    <name></name>
    <email></email>
    <link></link>
    <organization></organization>
</author>
</widget>
```

Do you have any idea, what the problem could be? Is there any log on the tv, which could be accessed to get more information?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was a problem in the index.html?!? After changing the order of the included files in the  (.css before .js) it's now working.

Interesting for me, that this causes a problem during sync between web server and tv

Answer (score 0):

Try zipping it up and putting it on the USB stick. Open SmartHub and insert the drive. You should see your app in the hub. If all goes well.

Comment: Even this doesn't work. When I open the SmartHub and then put in the USB stick, there comes up a popup, where you can chosse 'all, video, music'. The app doesn't appear.
I just started with a new untouched javascript project in Eclipse and tryed to sync it with the tv - which works.

Comment: I reduced more and more files from my app until I also got it synced with tv. It seems to be, that there is somewhere some javascript-coding the tv doesn't deal with (but the emulator does).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me when my completely tested app on other Samsung platforms(Samsung TV 2012,2013,2014) Failed to load on Samsung Blu-Ray player which have similar steps of loading app on TV.

After enormous test and trials i finally figured out that there was one particular jquery library jquery-latest.js which was stopping the app from being uploading to Blu-Ray player. So i re factored the app to another jquery library...and now app is working fine